# PHP Mail Inbox (IMAP) how to groupby each session Mail Inbox on PHP (Laravel)?

Tags: php, email, imap

I had a problem with grouping message for reply so we can see history of conversation.
Is there a way for grouping it? variable that I can get from imap:

1. id
2. date
3. subject
4. fromName
5. fromAddress
6. to
7. toString
8. cc
9. replyTo
10. messageId
11. textPlain
12. textHtml

Did I just need to store it to my DB and groupby it by fromAddress and subject?
but subject for reply is "Re: subject", right?

Comment: What is column `9: replyTo` please? Is it the self-referencing key to `1. id`?

Comment: On a traditional full featured email client, this is tracked by using the In-Reply-To and References headers.  These are then matched up to Message-Ids to find the parent message.

Comment: @doublesidedstickytape replyTo = an Array "sender email" => "sender name"

Comment: @Max so how I can detect parent id message now?

Comment: You get the message headers, and parse out References and In-Reply-To headers, then apply an algorithm like this one: https://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html